# Why is meta description of home page not appearing when I share the URL?

Tags: seo, jekyll, metadata, social-media

**Problem**

Whenever I share the URL https://decentr.net/ on social media it does not come with a meta description.

However, when I share the url https://decentr.net/blog/ or any other page the meta description does appear.

Here is a screenshot from telegram:

[image: Meta description telegram]

**Exception**

On whatsapp it does appear with meta description

Here is a screenshot from whatsapp

[image: Meta description whatsapp]

**Code**

front matter from Index.html (homepage)

```
---
layout: page
title: Earn by surfing the net
permalink: /
---
```

meta description from `<head>`

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="Decentr provides a web browser experience that gives surfing the internet a payable value for every user">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

SEO Jekyll plugin

```
<!-- Begin Jekyll SEO tag v2.5.0 --> 
<title>Earn by surfing the net</title> 
<meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v3.8.5" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Earn by surfing the net" /> 
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" /> 
<link rel="canonical" href="http://decentr.net//" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://decentr.net//" /> 
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Earn by surfing the net" /> 
<script type="application/ld+json"> {"publisher":{"@type":"Organization","logo":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"http://decentr.net//assets/logo.png"}},"@type":"WebSite","url":"http://decentr.net//","headline":"Earn by surfing the net","name":"Earn by surfing the net","@context":"http://schema.org"}</script> 
<!-- End Jekyll SEO tag -->
```

meta description from _config.yml

```
# Site settings
title: Earn by surfing the net
subtitle: "Decentr provides a web browser experience that gives surfing the internet a payable value for every user"
url: "http://decentr.net/"
```

**Github Repo:**

https://github.com/bomengeduld/decentr.net

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a question about Jekyll. Jekyll's job ends as soon as the HTML is generated. If you've confirmed that the meta description is in the generated HTML, then it's not really a question about Jekyll.

Instead, it's a question about the preview generator of the various social media sites. It's up to them whether they choose to use the meta description or not, and there isn't much we can help with there.

There are various tools that help you see how the social media preview crawlers understand your site:

- [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)
- [Twitter Card Validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator)
- [debug.iframely.com](http://debug.iframely.com/)

There are plenty of other tools on Google, I'd recommend a search.

My guess is that WhatsApp has a cached version of your site, and the meta description isn't updating. Again, I'd recommend searching for a tool that allows you to trigger a recrawl of your site.